# *** Assertion failure in -[RKObjectMapping addPropertyMapping:] crash in ios

Tags: restkit

just started few days back with RestKit,
need your review, where i am wrong..
getting crash in ios app: *** Assertion failure in -[RKObjectMapping addPropertyMapping:]

@interface VGShowCheckIn : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber * ad_units;

@property (nonatomic,strong) VGShowDetails * program;

@interface VGShowDetails : NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic)     NSString            *programTitle;

@property (copy, nonatomic)     NSString            *showId;

=======

RKObjectMapping *checkinMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[VGShowCheckIn class]];

```
[checkinMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{

                                                  @"ad_units" : @"ad_units",

                                                  @"program" : @"program"

                                                  }];





RKObjectMapping *showMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[VGShowDetails class]];

[showMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{

                                                  @"id"                                         :   @"showId",

                                                  @"title"                      :   @"programTitle",

                                                  }];
```

and app is crashing here :  [checkinMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"program" toKeyPath:@"program" withMapping:showMapping]];

and rest api response is:

{

```
data =     {

    "ad_units" = 3;

    program =         {

        id = SH017232340000;


        title = "Man v. Food Nation";
    }
 }
```

}

can any one guide me whats wrong in line: 
[checkinMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"program" toKeyPath:@"program" withMapping:showMapping]];

crash issue: *** Assertion failure in -[RKObjectMapping addPropertyMapping:]